# Extract coefficients from CoefficientRules

Tags: list-manipulation, coefficients

So CoffeficientRules[] gives  a vector {E1->c1,..., En->cn} for the N monimals Mi in the polynomial

```
    P = M1+...+Mi
```

I would like to separate the coefficients from the the rest, so I get two vectors

```
    V1 = {E1,...,En},

    V2 = {c1,..., cn}
```

Then I would like to have some function f(.) returning the powers of the original coefficient combinations. Then the original polynomial is found by the dot product

```
    P = f(V1).V2
```

Suggestions?

EDIT: I just found out that the two sought vectors can be found by a simple list manipulation.

```
    rule = CoefficientRules[myPolynomial, {a,b,c}]
    V1 = rule[[All, 1]] // MatrixForm
    V2 = rule[[All, 2]]  // MatrixForm
```

Now I just need to figure out how to transform V1 into a combination of {a,b,c} again. Say for instance that

```
    V[[1]] = {0,1,3}
```

then I want the function f returning

```
    f[V[[1], {a,b,c}] = a^0*b^1*c^3
```

Comment: Here its considered helpful and polite show you own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted mathematica code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing and see you have done your due diligence. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly.

Comment: You don't want to use `FromCoefficientRules[]`?

Comment: You can also use `Keys[rule]` and `Values[rule]`.